# Toggle visibility of circle layers, and popup on visible ones

Tags: popup, mouseevent, mapbox-gl, togglebutton, visible

I have succeeded in toggle 2 layers with red and green circles .
Now I would want to have a popup only *visible*  layer.
I can't get the visible layer, after toggle, and popup on it .
Guess it's a problem of workflow ...

I have a mapbox-gl  map, and 2 circle layers.
I succeeded in toggle the 2 layers visible/not visible, following
[Mapbox: Visibility none for all layers when one is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61514972/mapbox-visibility-none-for-all-layers-when-one-is-visible).
Then, I can't get mouseenter/hover  the visible layer and display a popup on it.